# I have to refresh the page manually while loading for it works in protractor

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, gulp-protractor

Well, I'm using chrome. 
When I run protractor the page begins to load and never finish to load until I refresh the page manually and then everything flow normally.
My page use Angular2, is built with MEAN stack.

Here my config file:

```js
// @datatype_void
require('ts-node/register');

exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3000',

  // use `npm run e2e`
  specs: [
    '../test/*.e2e.*.js'
  ],
  suites: {
    dashboard: '../test/Dashboard.e2e.testcase.js'
  },

  exclude: [],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  allScriptsTimeout: 40000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showTiming: true,
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000
  },
  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['show-fps-counter=true']
    }
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  },

  /**
   * Angular 2 configuration
   *
   * useAllAngular2AppRoots: tells Protractor to wait for any angular2 apps on the page instead of just the one matching
   * `rootEl`
   *
   */
   useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

And here is the first to run in my test:

```js
describe('This is Dashboard.', () => {

    email = 'alexis.gonzalez@agilezip.mx';
    pass = 'laslos157';
    browser.get('/');
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('.abcRioButton.abcRioButtonBlue')), 10000);
    element(by.css('.abcRioButton.abcRioButtonBlue')).click();
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function () {
            enterkeys(element(by.css('#Email')), email);
            element(by.css('#next')).click();
            browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('#Passwd')), 5000);
            enterkeys(element(by.css('#Passwd')), pass);
            element(by.css('#signIn')).click();
        });
    });
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    });
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($$('.al-sidebar-list-link').get(0)), 10000);
```

Comment: Well, the page finish to load but stay stuck on the load screen.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I could "fixed" by adding the lines:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
browser.navigate().refresh();
```

but I don't understand why I have to refresh the page. :(

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you don't have to use browser.waitForAngular() as Protractor automatically applies this command before every Web Driver action. Simply using browser.navigate.refresh() should also work.